# Adding a row in parse.com manually editing the data browser

Tags: parse-platform

What is happening? 
I did one app with parse.com before and I have no issues with adding a new row manually at the data browser. But on this new one I have added one with the test code from my app, but when trying to add one in parse it doesn't show the objectId and the createdAt date etc, that used to be generated automatically, and when saved it just delete the row. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Must have been something wrong temporarily at parse.com
It is working now as it used to do.
/Helen